# find word in nth row for column 1, and put new word in nth row for column 2

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using Excel, and am running into a problem that leads me to believe there might be a macro or other solution for this.  Hand editing is tedious!  :)

I am looking use the find/replace (or something else) tool in excel to do the following:

1. find a word in some nth row (the word will be found in column 1 of that row)
2. put a new (previously defined) word in the same row, but into the cell for column 2

Is this possible?

Thanks,
jml

Comment: So you want to put some data into column 2 for each row that has some other data that is found in column 1?

Comment: yes, precisely.

Comment: Are the words you're looking for part of some larger text, or by themselves?

Comment: part of larger text, but only within the first column's cells (aka, the word i am looking for might be "abc_", but the text in the found cell could be "abc_defg")

Comment: Does column2 start out empty?  Are you only looking for a single word or do you have a list?  A macro or user-defined function might be easier to implement, depending on your exact needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there some reason a formula won't work?

You can use this formula in the second column (starting with B1): `IF(ISERR(FIND("your_search_string",A1)),"replace_value_if_not_found","replace_value_if_found")`, then `Fill Down`.  If you have multiple "find/replace" values, you can next them in a third argument of the `if`.

If, once you've done this, you would rather have actual values in the cells instead of formulas, copy the entire column, then do `Paste Special` on the same column and select `Values` (instead of default/`Formulas`).

Comment: B1, then fill down.

Comment: hm; this sort of works, but if it's false, I get a "FALSE" printed into the cells in which it fails.

Comment: Edit - Please see my amended answer.

Comment: this won't work if i already have a value in the B1 cell.  it simply overwrites the value with the function.

Comment: Yes, it does - I thought you wanted to replace.  If not, what do you want to do?  Append, prepend, etc.?

Comment: It's not a replace function, per se.  If there is a value in B1 that already exists, which doesn't match the "search" via IF(), then it should be left alone.  But I can't enter in B1 for the "replace_value_if_not_found", since it causes a circular reference, and an error.

Comment: @jml: you can't have both a **formula** and a **value** in the very same cell. cheeken solution is a very nice way to deal with your issue, use the formula in another column and in the same (while adapting the formula) or in another (easy formula to create), you can get the result you want (and eventually, just hide column B and C)